# Display an object fetched from Amazon lambda in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, amazon-s3

I am trying to invoke an Amazon Lambda function to access a specific image file stored in my Amazon S3 bucket. I have been successful in this regard and I get an image in the form as mentioned below:

```
\u0006D�������\u0012V���ϯC�w�����\t�iW7�`�#.\u0007��a��\u000fƚv......
```

**What is this exact stream type that is being returned?**

Now, I am trying to display this in a windows form as an image:

*Program.cs*

```
static async Task Main()
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form1 form = new Form1();
        Application.Run(form);
        string key = "xyz.jfif";
        string result = await GetLambdaResponse("{\"type\":\"get\",\"key\":\"" + key + "\"}");
        form.UpdateImage(result);
    }
```

*Form1.cs*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PictureBox pb1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pb1 = new PictureBox();
        pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.Controls.Add(pb1);
    }

    public void UpdateImage(string result)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(result));

        if(pb1 != null)
        {
            pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the AWS function doesn't get invoked until *after* I close the empty form that gets shown, and then I get the following exception in the *Image.fromStream()* method.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
```

I need some pointers on how to correctly convert the response stream I am getting into something that can be shown as an image in the windows form.

Comment: Code under `Application.Run` won't be called until the main form is closed.  You need to place the code elsewhere.  One option is to put it in `Main` _before_ `Application.Run` and passing it to the form's constructor.

Comment: @Zer0 thanks that helped. But do you know how to display it in the windows form? What is the exact form of this stream?

Comment: What file format is the image?

Comment: @Zer0 its in .jfif image format

Comment: Try `pb1.Image =  new Bitmap(stream);`.  `Bitmap` inherits from `Image` and supports JPEGs.

Comment: @Zer0 didnt work. Same exception :(

Comment: Probably easiest thing now is host any image that doesn't work somewhere so that I can reproduce then fix on my end.

Comment: @Zer0 https://test-nom-snaps.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/buizel.jfif